# Authorization: How to handle mutiple (dozen or more) requirements

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a set of tables in our database with users, permissions, and a join that maps which users have what permissions.

Looking at [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-3.1), the following is an example of how policies and the requirement(s) are set up on `Startup`:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllersWithViews();
    services.AddRazorPages();
    services.AddAuthorization(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy("AtLeast21", policy =>
            policy.Requirements.Add(new MinimumAgeRequirement(21)));
    });
}
```

And here is an example of a handler for multiple requirements:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using PoliciesAuthApp1.Services.Requirements;

public class PermissionHandler : IAuthorizationHandler
{
    public Task HandleAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context)
    {
        var pendingRequirements = context.PendingRequirements.ToList();

        foreach (var requirement in pendingRequirements)
        {
            if (requirement is ReadPermission)
            {
                if (IsOwner(context.User, context.Resource) ||
                    IsSponsor(context.User, context.Resource))
                {
                    context.Succeed(requirement);
                }
            }
            else if (requirement is EditPermission ||
                     requirement is DeletePermission)
            {
                if (IsOwner(context.User, context.Resource))
                {
                    context.Succeed(requirement);
                }
            }
        }

        //TODO: Use the following if targeting a version of
        //.NET Framework older than 4.6:
        //      return Task.FromResult(0);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    private bool IsOwner(ClaimsPrincipal user, object resource)
    {
        // Code omitted for brevity

        return true;
    }

    private bool IsSponsor(ClaimsPrincipal user, object resource)
    {
        // Code omitted for brevity

        return true;
    }
}
```

My intention is to check my database tables within the handler to validate that the user has a setting that corresponds to the policy. To check if a user can upload files, the policy might look like this:

```
    services.AddAuthorization(config =>
    {
        config.AddPolicy("CanUploadFiles", policy => policy.Requirements.Add(new CanDoRequirement("CanUploadFiles")));
    });
```

Using an `[Authorize]` attribute for a given policy, I can check that within the handler. I have that much working.

Question: Given that I might have 10-20 separate "CanDo…" permissions in our table, is there a better way to set these up rather than have separate lines in `AddAuthorization()`?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I'm not aware of any shortcuts when configuring the 20-ish requirements and policies that would remove the separate lines in startup, but you could consider implementing a sort of custom resource based authorization rather than a policy based one, policy-based being a declarative one. Declarative meaning the policy is pre-configured. Like so: `[Authorize("policy")]`.

By using imperative authorization, rather than declarative, you would remove the need for x amount of policies to be configured. Instead of saying "Authorize this method", you let the framework take care of the authorization itself.

Consider the following requirements

A user must be authenticated.
That user can only upload a file if they satisfy the CanUploadFiles which is a boolean on the user's record in the database.

Now consider the following example

You have created your own ICustomAuthorizationHandler, somewhat similar to the the ASP.NET Core's IAuthorizationHandler, with the exception that you won't be satisfying a policy, but instead you will feed it a 'CanDoPermission' and it will return true or false if that user has that specific 'flag'.

```cs
public class FileController : Controller
{
    private ICustomAuthorizationService _authService
    public FileController(ICustomAuthorizationService authService)
    {
        _authService = authService;
    }

    [Authorize]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Upload(IFormFile file)
    {
        var authResult = await _authService.AuthorizeAsync(User, "CanDoUpload");
        if (!authResult.Succeeded)
        {
            return new ForbidResult();
        }
        // Process upload
        return View();
    }
}
```

This way, there wouldn't have to be policies nor requirements configured for checking if the user can upload a file. But, you would need to take care of a lot of the stuff that you get for 'free' by simply going for policies and configuring them in AddAuthorization.